# XCode starts loading non-retina on retina display

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Somehow XCode starts partially draw non-retina images on both retina iPhone and Simulator. You can see image with standard searchbar below, it is even not my graphics, but as you can see magnifier is pixelated, while text is retina. Some of both my and system graphics are still retina, some not. I'm trying to clean project and restart XCode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's because I initialized my ViewController before `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
@UIApplicationMain 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let viewController = UITableViewController()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // add viewController to view hierarchy
    }
}
```